# How does one tell if a value is statistically significantly different than the rest of the obtained values?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

Let's say I have some number of values--say 5 different values {0.118, 0.162, 0.353, 0.206, 0.265}--and I want to determine if any one of those values (e.g. 0.118) is significantly different from the rest. How can I do this without having any other information available?

I've searched all over online, but all results seem to point to the t-test, which I can't do because I don't have an accepted population mean nor two means to compare to each other. I simply have a list of data points and I want to know if a certain value is statistically significant. (I'm assuming the data is normally distributed based on some other tests I ran but I'm interested in knowing how the answer to this question changes if the data isn't normal.) I also thought of using a simple outlier test, but that doesn't output a p-value which I would need.

A similar problem is described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141988/how-to-determine-if-a-value-is-significantly-larger-than-other-values), except I can't use a simulation for my purposes. I'm doing my calculations in R, so while I mostly just want a list of tests I could use, adding in some R code would also be appreciated (though not necessary).

Comment: It's not clear why you can't use any sort of simulation, but it seems like what you are interested in is "outlier detection" rather than statistical significance. However, with such a small sample this isn't going to be possible with any sort of confidence.

Comment: *Every* value in your set differs from the rest.  For "significant" to apply, you need to posit (a) a probability model and (b) a statistical hypothesis.  Could you edit your post to provide this information?

Comment: @BryanKrause is right that this is outlier detection; such tests do allow for samples this small, though you may need to interpolate p-values.  Try Dixon's or Grubb's Test.

Answer (score 2):

The question of statistical significance requires knowledge of the variability surrounding those numbers. If those numbers were population parameters, there'd be no statistical test necessary (they *are* different). However, if those numbers are sample means, the extent to which they are *different* depends on how variable the raw data are. For example, if I have means of 5 and 6, each with sd of 0.001, these look very different than means of 5 and 6 with sd of 100.

So you see, statistical significance is meaningless without variability estimates. If you have this information, you can conduct tests.